# Dynamic graphics rendering on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

What I want to achieve is some way of supplying dynamically generated visual content that the user of a device could interact with - touch icons, text links, images etc embedded within some graphic image generated either on the phone or on a server. I would need, pinch, zoom, rotate functionality aswell.

Is it possible to render graphics dynamically within the iPhone's UI? So, for example, would it be feasible to supply an XML file to a device and have that render a custom map within the device? Would you have all the pinch-zoom, rotate and click on icons type functionality of a normal UI?

Alternatively, could I pre-render a png on a server and supply that to the device?

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Quartz2D to help you do the custom drawing, it should do pretty much anything you want to do....

Answer (score 1):

Sure, any of those are possible.

You'll probably need to write some code to interpret your XML file and generate an appropriate `UIView` and then embed that in the window.

And you're totally welcome to download images and display them in a `UIImageView`.

Comment: Thanks dave. How difficult would it be to map a user's current gps to some custom rendered graphic map? presumably, if all the above are possible, this should be too?

Comment: In otherwords, use current location to place an icon within a graphic that represents the users current locale ..

Comment: @Malcom sure you can do that.  You have to do all the work yourself, though.